# Android Studio get a txt file from web in widget

Tags: java, android

I am new to android studio and just want an app to do one thing: check if the bytewerk is open (domain is **stats.bytewerk.org/status.txt** just one word either open or closed) and display it on a widget. But I tried all kind of httpconections like volley or okhttp, but never got a result. I already added the uses permission in the manifest.

1:

```
public class StatusWidget<appWidgetId> extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                int appWidgetId) throws IOException {
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.status_widget);
        new GetNotePadFileFromServer().execute();

        //views.setViewVisibility(R.id.bytewerk_online, 0);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            try {

                updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    }
}public class GetNotePadFileFromServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String TextHolder;
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://stats.bytewerk.org/status.txt");

            BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            TextHolder = "";
            String TextHolder2 = "";
            while ((TextHolder2 = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {

                TextHolder += TextHolder2;
            }
            bufferReader.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException malformedURLException) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            malformedURLException.printStackTrace();
            TextHolder = malformedURLException.toString();

        } catch (IOException iOException) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            iOException.printStackTrace();

            TextHolder = iOException.toString();
        }

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void finalTextHolder) {

        textView.setText(TextHolder);

        super.onPostExecute(finalTextHolder);
    }
```

2:

```
final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
// ...

// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url ="http://www.google.com";

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
        textView.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        textView.setText("That didn't work!");
    }
});

// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
queue.add(stringRequest);
```

And the other examples on the offical website
of course i already implemented

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Please show your attempts.

Comment: Show all your attempts code that you write. Then we all can help you better and always try to showing attempts when asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was my solution:

```
    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                final int appWidgetId) {
        final RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.status_widget);
// ...

// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
       RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        String url ="http://stats.bytewerk.org/status.txt";
// Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                        if (response.equals("open")) {
                            views.setViewVisibility(R.id.status_online, 1);
                        } else {
                            views.setViewVisibility(R.id.status_offline, 1);
                        }
                        //views.setTextViewText(R.id.text, "Yeah!" + response);
                        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                views.setViewVisibility(R.id.status_nointernet, 1);
                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

            }
        });
        queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add internet permission to your `Manifest.xml` and volley works, This line:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

before `application` tag.

Hope this helps.

Comment: 2, that one which uses Volley